# Finding mean, variance from a CSV Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variance

I have been writing some code that is pretty straight forward, plotting values from a column in a dataframe.   This values are stores into a variable called **numbers**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r'C://Desktop/Plot/output.csv', delimiter=";", encoding='unicode_escape')


data=df[df['description']=='Someone starts']['num_1'].values
numbers= data   #storing the values of the column to dev_x
plt.plot(numbers)
```

I have been trying to also get the variance and the mean of these values that are stored into numbers 
Using  `df.var('numbers')`  seems not to working. Would appreciate some help.

I

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you have a dataframe df:

is this what you are after?

```
import numpy as np
df['numbers'].mean() #will give you the mean
np.std(df['numbers']) #will give you the stdev
```

Comment: I have updated the question and added more of the code. and I want to find the varance

Comment: square of the standard deviation is variance. But anyway you can also use np.var(df['numbers']).. does it solve your problem?

Comment: @StupidWolf, when using your line   ```np.var(df['numbers'])```   I am getting the error  ```KeyError: 'numbers'```